# UITableViewCell subclassed in swift 3 has contentView always of 320 points

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to create a UILabel in my subclassed UITableViewCell to make it the full width of the cell. But the contentView is always 320pt if in iPhone 7 or 7+.

The code is:

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class ReuseableCell: SwipeTableViewCell
{
    public var test = UILabel();

    var animator: Any?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);

        // Always 320pt and I want full width of the table cell
        var width = self.contentView.frame.width;

        test = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 100));


        test.text = "Lorem ipsum...";

        ...
```

I have been stuck on this for 2 nights. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use autolayout instead of setting frame?

Comment: Show your tableview cell and try to use `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` instead of `self.contentView.frame.width`

Answer (score 2):

You can try auto-layout

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);


    test = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero);

    self.contentView.addSubview(test)

    test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    test.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    test.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    test.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    test.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    test.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Your label inside  `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)` but to read correct frame you have  override `override func layoutSubviews()`   and read correct frame

Comment: layoutSubviews is invoked multiple times

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to set constrains to your 'UITableView'. Try set tableview width constrain equal to superview width.

In ViewController:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView,  attribute: .width,  relatedBy: .equal,  toItem: self.view,  attribute: .width,  multiplier: 1.0,  constant: 0))
```